# plt.subplot_adjust() not working correctly

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am making some density plots like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
import matplotlib
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import InsetPosition
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter
import random

matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 16})
matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'in'
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.direction'] = 'in'

x = random.sample(range(1, 10001), 1000)
y = random.sample(range(1, 10001), 1000)



def myplot(x, y, s, bins=1000):
    heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=bins)
    heatmap = gaussian_filter(heatmap, sigma=s)

    extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]
    return heatmap.T, extent
cmap = cm.YlOrRd

fig, (ax, ax1, cax) = plt.subplots(ncols = 3, figsize = (15, 5),
                       gridspec_kw={"width_ratios":[1,1, 0.5]})
img, extent = myplot(x, y, 20)
im = ax.imshow(img, extent = extent, origin = 'lower', cmap = cmap)
ax.text(0.05, 0.92, '$R^2$ = {}'.format(np.round(r2_score(x, y), 2)), fontsize=14, color = 'k', transform = ax.transAxes)
ax.plot(ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_ylim(), ls="--", c=".3")
ax.set_xlabel("Black Sky")
ax.set_ylabel("Blue Sky")

img2, extent2 = myplot(x, y, 20)
ax1.imshow(img2, extent = extent2, origin = 'lower', cmap = cmap)
ax1.text(0.05, 0.92, '$R^2$ = {}'.format(np.round(r2_score(x, y), 2)), fontsize=14, color = 'k', transform = ax1.transAxes)
ax1.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
ax1.yaxis.set_ticks([])
ax1.plot(ax1.get_xlim(), ax1.get_ylim(), ls="--", c=".3")
ax1.set_xlabel("White Sky")


ip = InsetPosition(ax1, [1.05,0,0.05,1]) 

cax.set_axes_locator(ip)

fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax, ax=[ax,ax1], use_gridspec = True)

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.1, hspace=0)
```

which gives me a plot like this:

[image]

No matter what I change `wspace` to the plot stays the same.  I think this is because when I turn of the y-axis in `ax1` I am just making the text blank instead of removing the y-axis all together.  Is there a way to do this so that I can make the width spacing between the figures closer together?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're concerned with the positioning, not the contents of the plots?

Comment: Just to make sure, if you change e.g. `wspace=0.5`, you will see a clear difference. `wspace` sets the *minimal* distance between plots. So best ask for what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes I am only concerned with the positioning between plots, what I am trying to achieve is a smaller whitespace between plots on the y-axis. Setting `wspace=0` does not actually reduce the whitespace when in fact it should make it so there is none at all.

Comment: Ahh, I see, I misunderstood that.  I want to shrink the existing whitespace is my desired output so that the two plots are closer together. sharey = True does this, but it also changes my units on the plots to those from the density plot which I don't want.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [plt.tightlayout()](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/demo_tight_layout.html?highlight=plt%20tight_layout)?

Comment: I tried that one too, and while it usually works it doesn't do it in this case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As commented, `wspace` sets the *minimal* distance between plots. This distance may be larger in case of equal aspect axes. Then it will depend on the figure size, figure aspect and image aspect.

#### A. Use automatic aspect

You may set `aspect = "auto"` in your `imshow` plots,

```
ax.imshow(..., aspect = "auto")
```

[image]

#### B. Adjust the subplot parameters

You may set the left or right subplot parameter to something smaller. E.g.

```
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.0, hspace=0, right=0.7)
```

[image]

#### C. Adjust the figure size

Using a smaller figure width, which is closer to the actual image aspect will also reduce whitespace around the figure.

E.g, making the figure only 11 inches wide and using 5% padding on the right,

```
plt.subplots(..., figsize = (11, 5))
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.0, hspace=0, right=.95)
```

[image]